# Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $xf(xf(x)-4)-1=4x$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the following is valid:
> $$xf\big(xf(x)-4\big)-1=4x$$

---

All I could do is:

- $f(x)> {4\over x}$ for all $x$ so $f(x)>0$ for all $x$.
- $(4,\infty )\subseteq {\rm Range}(f)$, since $$f(xf(x)-4)={4x+1\over x} >4$$
- Function $g(x)=xf(x)-4$ is injective:
  \begin{align}g(x_1)=g(x_2) &\implies  f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2))\\&\implies {4x_1+1\over x_1}={4x_2+1\over x_2} \\&\implies x_1=x_2\end{align}
- Function $g$ satisfies $$\boxed{xg(g(x)) -(4x+1)g(x)+4x=0}$$

Comment: This is probably unnecessary but I managed to tighten the lower bound: $$f(x)>\frac{20x+4}{4x^2+x}$$ The process is *way* to long to be actually typed in a comment, so a sketch-ish something, words only: I tried to "reuse" the given condition by saying $xf(x)-4$ is my "*new*" $x$. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think the idea is to substitute $x$ by $g(x)=x\,f(x)-4$ repeatedly.  You will then see that $$g(x)\,f\big(g(x)\big)>4\tag{*}\,.$$  However, you know $f\big(g(x)\big)=4+\dfrac1x$, so (\*) becomes $$f(x)>\frac{20x+4}{x(4x+1)}\,.$$

Comment: Look at this [comparison plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B4%2Fx%2C%2820x%2B4%29%2F%28x*%284x%2B1%29%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C5%7D%5D).  I think the supremum of the values after the repeated iterations suggested above will be the value of $f$.

Comment: @Batominovski Yeah, nice! Anyway, the continuation of my comment, which Batominovski has already done/shown: Then I obtain$$4+\frac{1}{xf(x)-4}=f((4x+1)f(x)-20-\frac 4x)$$ Then use $f(x)>4/x$ on RHS. Rearrange to obtain above inequality, the right hand side of which is always greater than $\frac 4x$.

Comment: @Batominovski: Did you get the second iteration stuff by hand? If yes, could you sketch the method?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar  Not by hand.  By [my best friend](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B1%2B1%2F%284*x%29%3E1%2F%28x*y-4%29%2B1%2F%284%28x*y-4%29%2B1%29%2Cy%5D).  It looks hopeless for the third iteration, though.

Comment: Asymptotically, I think $f(x)\approx \dfrac{16}{3x}$.  See how good this approximation is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B4%2Fx%2C%2820x%2B4%29%2F%28x*%284x%2B1%29%29%2C1%2F8+%28%28144+x+%2B+31%29%2F%284+x%5E2+%2B+x%29+%2B+sqrt%28%28512+x%5E2+%2B+32+x+%2B+1%29%2F%28x%5E2+%284+x+%2B+1%29%5E2%29%29%29%2C16%2F%283*x%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C5%7D%5D).

Comment: @Batominovski But if you plug that in, it *nearly* works out: $$4x-1=4x$$ An impossible condition :(

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar I know.  I assumed $f(x)=k/x$ to see what would be the best $k$.  It is a bit painful that it *almost* worked out.

Comment: $f(x)=4+\frac 4x$ works if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse but see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699486/using-steffensens-method-trying-to-prove-phix-0e

Comment: @timon92 How you found it?

Comment: @Aqua I don't remember, this was like 6 months ago...

Comment: The following recurrence is easily derived.
$$
x_{k+1} = x_ky_k-4 \\
y_{k+1} = 4+1/x_k
$$
When $\,y_k = 4+4/x_k\,$ we have $\,x_{k+1} = 4x_k\,$ giving $\,y_{k+1} = 4+4/x_{k+1}\,$ as expected.
For $\,x_k=1\,$ and $\,y_k=5\,$ we find a single stationary point: $\,x_{k+1}=1\,$ and $\,y_{k+1}=5\,$.
Numerical experiments indicate that _all_ other solutions for $\,x\to\infty\,$ are approximated best by $\,y=4+4/x\,$.

Answer (score 6):

*Partial answer:*

Consider the equation $xf(xf(x)-a)-1=ax$ for $a>0$ so that $$f(xf(x)-a)=a+\frac1x.$$ This means that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(xf(x)-a)=a$ so that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=a$. Further, we have $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(xf(x)-a)=+\infty$$ and since $f(x)>a/x\implies\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}xf(x)=a$.

Let $m,n$ be integers such that $m<-1$ and $n>0$. Notice that $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=m}^na_kx^k$$ implies $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}xf(x)=a$ so $a_{-1}=a$ and $a_i=0$ for all $m\le i<-1$. Likewise we have $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=a$ so $a_0=a$ and $a_j=0$ for all $0<j\le n$. Thus if $f$ is a finite Laurent polynomial then the only solution to the functional equation is $$f(x)=a+\frac ax.$$

Comment: I think the last paragraph of your answer is incorrect (unless you have some constraint on $b$, for example, $b>0$).  But the Laurent series analysis is great.  When $a>1$, $f(x)=\dfrac{a^2}{(a-1)x}$ is a solution to $x\,f\big(x\,f(x)-a\big)-b=ax$ when $b=0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

Let $g(x)=xf(x)-4$.

Our functional equation becomes

> $$\frac{g\circ g(x)+4}{g(x)}=4+\frac1x$$

If there exists an invertible function $\phi(x):\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ such that $g(x)=\phi(\phi^{-1}(x)+1)$, direct substitution gives
$$\frac{\phi(z+2)+4}{\phi(z+1)}=4+\frac1{\phi(z)}$$
or $$\phi(z+2)=\left[4+\frac1{\phi(z)}\right]\phi(z+1)-4$$
by substituting $z=\phi^{-1}(x)$.

Clearly, this recurrence relation extends a $\phi(x)$ defined arbitrarily on $(0,2)$ to the whole $\mathbb R^+$. By computing $\phi^{-1}(x)$ this method generates a large class of solution to the functional equation.

(Of course there are certain restrictions on $\phi(x)$ on $(0,2)$ so that $\phi(x)$ is invertible.)

The solution $f(x)=4+\frac4x$ corresponds to $g(x)=4x$ and $\phi(x)=k\cdot 4^x$ where $k$ is a positive constant.

A feature of this special solution is that $\phi(x)$ is continuous. In contrast, if rather arbitrary values are assigned to $\phi(x)$ on $(0,2)$, a discontinuous solution may yield. Below is the graph of $\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x) = x+1$ on $(0,2)$.

[image]